# Clean URLs with unused GET variables, Laravel

Tags: url, laravel, get, clean-urls

I noticed that the URLs here on StackOverflow have a GET variable "questions" followed by the ID of the question. But after that, they also have the title of the question in the URL.

E.g. /questions/1234/name-of-question

Now, if you alter the question name, and go to something like /questions/1234/foo, you will still end up at /questions/1234/name-of-question.

This allows for some good SEO, because the "name-of-question" bit is added to the URL when the question is created, I assume. And when googling, it will show up as very relevant, since if you google "name-of-question", the search query is a part of the URL.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this using Laravel? Or even more interestingly, how is it accomplished in general?

Comment: htaccess involved here. GET params still exist, so at first PHP gets question ID, then it queries question name from database, replaces all the specific symbols with `-` and checks if supplied name is same as in database, on case it is not - header to ther correct one

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27658499/1903366)